# Render Problem in Main Activity file - Android Studio

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, render

Render problem occurs in Main activity. This issue does not affect the usability of the application but makes it very difficult to make adjustments to the layouts contained within the main activity.
There is not more info is available for this issue, I have tried following the stack trace with no luck.

**Image As Requested by Comment: **
[Layout Issues - Render Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5upz.png)

Here is the full Stack Trace

**Stack Trace**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7200)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1925)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl_Accessor.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl_Accessor.java:24)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.requestFitSystemWindows(Layout.java:385)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestApplyInsets(View.java:10804)
    at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(ViewCompat.java:2426)
    at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$Api21Impl$1.onApplyWindowInsets(ViewCompat.java:4774)
    at android.view.View.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(View.java:10514)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7191)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.brokenDispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7203)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchApplyWindowInsets(ViewGroup.java:7193)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl.java:1925)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl_Accessor.dispatchApplyInsets(ViewRootImpl_Accessor.java:24)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.requestFitSystemWindows(Layout.java:385)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestFitSystemWindows(View.java:10796)
    at android.view.View.requestApplyInsets(View.java:10804)
    at androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.requestApplyInsets(ViewCompat.java:2426)
    at com.google.android.material.internal.ViewUtils$4.onViewAttachedToWindow(ViewUtils.java:250)
    at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:19586)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3430)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3437)
    at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:404)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:713)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$6(RenderTask.java:844)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

---

**XML Code:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.team21.garageapplication.activity.MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/navHostMain"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/md_grey_900"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottomNav"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/md_grey_900"
        app:itemIconTint="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:itemTextColor="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/navHostMain"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**Main Activity Code: (As suggested by comment):**

```kotlin
package com.team21.garageapplication.activity

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.navigation.NavController
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment
import androidx.navigation.fragment.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.team21.garageapplication.R
import com.team21.garageapplication.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.team21.garageapplication.helper.SharedPreferenceHelper
import com.team21.garageapplication.misc.Constants
import com.team21.garageapplication.models.Garage
import dagger.hilt.android.AndroidEntryPoint

@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    private val TAG = "MainActivity"
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Started")

        initNavigation()

        navigateToMapFragmentIfNeeded(intent)

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate Ended")
    }

    override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        navigateToMapFragmentIfNeeded(intent)
    }


    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        navController = findNavController(R.id.navHostMain)
        return navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
    }


    private fun visibilityNavElements(navController: NavController){
        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
            when(destination.id){
                R.id.catalog,
                R.id.employees,
                R.id.appList,
                R.id.executeApptFragment,
                R.id.currentAppointment -> binding.bottomNav.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                else -> {

                    binding.bottomNav.visibility = View.GONE
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun initNavigation(){
        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostMain) as NavHostFragment
        navController = navHostFragment.navController

        binding.bottomNav.setupWithNavController(navController)
        binding.bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemReselectedListener {
            /* NO-OP */
        }

        visibilityNavElements(navController)

        val navGraph = navController.navInflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph)
        if(SharedPreferenceHelper.getObject<Garage>(Constants.GARAGE_KEY) == null){
            navGraph.startDestination = R.id.selectGarageFragment
        }else{
            navGraph.startDestination = R.id.logInFragment
        }

        navController.graph = navGraph
    }

    private fun navigateToMapFragmentIfNeeded(intent: Intent?){
        if(intent?.action == Constants.ACTION_SHOW_MAP_FRAGMENT){
            val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostMain) as NavHostFragment
            navHostFragment.findNavController().navigate(R.id.actionGlobalMapFragment)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You state in the post that there is no other relevant code, but please post the activity code. It will be very useful to help figure out what is going on. In general the more code for reference, the better people will be able to help

Comment: I have added the requested code